# how to sort each line on the file in scala?

Tags: scala

I want sorted list of the names, last name first, one per line. Names will be ordered by the number of characters in the first name in ascending order, shortest first. Within each group of names of each length, they will be ordered by the number of characters in the last name in ascending order, shortest first.

Example:

#### xxx xxxxx

#### xxx xxxxx

#### xxx xxxxxx

#### xxx xxxxxxx

#### xxxx xxx

#### xxxx xxxxx

#### xxxx xxxxxxx

i append the name to a list of list like this
List(List(Samantha, Sanderfur), List(Kathlene, Lamonica), List(Dixie, Crooker), List(Domitila, Rutigliano))

and i want sort this list of list. Idk how should i sort this, or some other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site rewards effort. What have you tried? Show us code that doesn't work so we can see where you need help.

Comment: ty guys for help me. I used sort with to sort this list of list.

Answer (score 2):

try below code:

```
val names = List(("Jack","Wilson"),("Alex","Jao"),("Jack","Wildorsowman"),
    ("Jack","Wiliamson"),("Alex","Joan"),("Alex","J."))

println(names.sortBy( x => (x._1.length(),x._2.length())))
```

Result:

```
List((Alex,J.), (Alex,Jao), (Alex,Joan), (Jack,Wilson), (Jack,Wiliamson), (Jack,Wildorsowman))
```

UPDATED with suggestion from @GalNaor -

```
val names = `List(List("Jack","Wilson"),List("Alex","Jao"),List("Jack","Wildorsowman"),List("Jack","Wiliamson"),List("Alex","Joan"),List("Alex","J."))`

println(names.sortBy{ case List(x,y) => (x.length(),y.length())})
```

Result:

```
List(List(Alex, J.), List(Alex, Jao), List(Alex, Joan), List(Jack, Wilson), List(Jack, Wiliamson), List(Jack, Wildorsowman))
```

Comment: To make your solution to work with the required input, you need to change your `sortBy(..` to `sortBy{case List(x,y)..`.

Comment: @GalNaor Thanks. I missed to notice that it is List of List.

Comment: happy to help +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
val input = List(List("aa","bbb"), List("a", "bb"), List("aaaa", "b"), List("aa", "bb"))

val tupleInput = input.map{case List(a,b) => (a,b)} 
// List((aa,bbb), (a,bb), (aaaa,b), (aa,bb))

val sortedMapValues = tupleInput.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.sorted) 
// Map(a -> List((a,bb)), aaaa -> List((aaaa,b)), aa -> List((aa,bb), (aa,bbb)))

val sortedMapKeys = scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap(sortedMapValues.toArray:_*) 
// Map(a -> List((a,bb)), aa -> List((aa,bb), (aa,bbb)), aaaa -> List((aaaa,b)))

val result = sortedMapKeys.map{case (_, a) => a}

// result = List(List((a,bb)), List((aa,bb), (aa,bbb)), List((aaaa,b)))
```

You can play with it [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/MYJSFAH/0)

Another one-liner solution can be like this ([here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/MYJSFAH/2)) - Thanks to @Anupam Kumar (a little adjustment need to be done to make his solution fit the input required):

```
val result = input.sortBy{case List(x,y) => (x.length(),y.length())}
```

Thanks @jwvh for the making it even shorter.

Comment: You don't need the `map()` ops. Convert to `Tuple2[Int,Int]` inside the `sortBy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ty guys for help me. I use sortwith to sort list of list 
here is my code

```
val s=v.sortWith((x,a)=>if(x(0).length==a(0).length){
  x(1).length<a(1).length
}
else{
  x(0).length<a(0).length
})
var z=""
for(i<- s){
  z=i(0)+" "+i(1)
  println(z)
}
```